# IntelliJで.envを開こうとするとテキストエディタが開いてしまう

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJで.envを開こうとするとテキストエディタが開いてしまうのですが、IntelliJで.envを開きたいです。

当人、独学のため専門用語などわからないかもしれないのでステップバイステップで教えていただけると感謝します。

Comment: 「intelliJで.envを開こうとすると」は、具体的にどのような操作をしようとしていますか？

Comment: 例えば、intelliJでtext.pyを開くという行為の意味は　左側のprojectからディレクトリを選びtext.pyをダブルクリックすることを意味します。

Comment: 関連付けの問題のようですが、ご利用のOSはなんですか？

Comment: Macbook pro 13 inchです！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ公式ドキュメントに関連付けの方法が記載されておりました。こちらを参考に、 `.env` 拡張子で関連付けの作成をしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

[ファイル・タイプの作成および登録 - 公式ヘルプ | IntelliJ IDEA](https://pleiades.io/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！！！！

Comment: この回答で解決しましたら、承認済み（✓ボタン）にしてください。